# The char "\u200B" is automatically added to the EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I am working on an Android Application in which one I would like to compare some string values in `EditText`.

For example, in a first `EditText`, I start to entry "dav" and then select "David" from the keyboard suggestions. In a second `EditText`, I start to entry "dav", then select "David" from the keyboard suggestions and then correct the content to "Dav".

Every seems to be OK. If I retrieve the content of the `EditText` (with `getEditableText().toString().trim()`) the debugger tells me that "David" is a word composed by 5 characters and "Dav" a word composed by 3 characters.

If now I click on the `EditText` that contains "Dav" and I select "David" from the keyboard suggestions, the debugger tells me that the word "David" is composed by 6 characters. The last character is "\u200B".

Why this character is automatically add and how can I remove it in a generic way ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: is it happens all time or in case of selection of suggestions? if suggestions only then it will adding space by default you can use trim() at the time getting value

Comment: @Pavan : It appears each time I select a suggestion from an not empty EditText. When I select a suggestion from an empty EditText I do not have the issue. I already use the `trim()` method after the `toString()` one.

Comment: as suggestions may containing extra space which causing this, is trim() working or u facing any other problem?

Answer (score 1):

`\u200B` is a unicode character [*zero width space*](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm). It seems to me it's being added by the keyboard you are using. I assume if you change your keyboard it's possible you won't see that behavior.

One way to handle that is replacing that character and dealing with the actual `String`:

```
    @Test
    public void zero_space_character() {
        String David = "David\u200B";
        String theRealDavid = David.replace("\u200B", "");
        assertNotEquals(David, theRealDavid);
        assertEquals("David", theRealDavid);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be getText(). toString(). trim().

Comment: Hi, I already try with the `getText()` method but the result is exactly the same. And I cannot use the `trim()` method after the `getText()` one.

Comment: @Sushobh It should be getText(). toString(). trim() not getText(). trim(). toString()